# CSR, Inconsistency between indices and indptr

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Since my feature matrix was too large, I used np.savez to to compress it. The resulting npy file values' as follows:
indptr: 1, 21, 201, 219, 262, 285 ...
indices: 125, 6, 921, 493, 218, 824 ...

I think if an element of indices is lower than the previous element, we are in next row due to csr data read direction. Specifically, in indices, 6 is lower than 125. So the second data should be in the next row but indptr states that the second row start with the 21st data. What is the possible problem?

Comment: The indices within a row do not have to be sorted.  Attribute `,has_sorted_indices` is True if they are sorted, False otherwise.  There are methods to  `.sort_indices`.  These apply, of course to the matrix before saving.

Comment: The newest `scipy` has a `save_npz` method,`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43014503/save-npz-method-missing-from-scipy-sparse.  It uses `savez`, probably like you do.  Check its code.

Comment: Alright, so what I understand is that if indices are not sorted, data is not sorted in a row as well. Thus, data and indices still match. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, they go together.

Comment: Thank you very much. I solved the problem. Can you help me with this issue as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43471419/matlab-crashes-during-importing-large-non-formatted-data